# Chart.JS - Set fixed X and Y axis values in time chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently attempting to use Chart.JS to create a line graph, displaying brightness percentages (0-100%) of an LED over 24H.

I'm trying to configure the chart to have set X and Y axis scales.

I need the X axis to display every hour (0,1,2,3... 21,22,23,24), and the Y axis to display values up to 100, going up by 10 (0,10,20... 90,100). I'm unsure how to get it to work. So far I've tried "unitStepSize: 1" and "min: 00:00" + "max: 24:00" as below, but these do not work in the way I had hoped. How can I get this graph to display correctly? Here's my code:

````
var labels = result.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH:mm'));
var data = result.map(e => +e.y);

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'White',
         data: data,
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
               format: "H:mm",
           unit: 'hour',
           unitStepSize: '1',
           tooltipFormat: "H:mm A",
               displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'H',
                  min: '00:00',
                  max: '24:00',
               }
            }
         }]
      },
   }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under options / scale try something like this: --> see yAxes

```
 options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Month'
                            }
                        }],
                    yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                steps: 10,
                                stepValue: 5,
                                max: 100
                            }


                           }]


 ...
    }
```